# Reset DropZone with Fade

Tags: image-processing, dropzone.js

I have a DropZone form that I'm resetting after each upload. My needs dictate one upload at a time as the user makes selections indicating particular attributes.

The pertinent part of my DropZone options:

```
 maxFiles: 1,
 success: function (file) {
 this.removeFile(file);
 }
```

This is working *perfectly* for my purposes with a minor issue in that after a successful upload the thumbnail and checkmark disappear so rapidly that the user has no idea it happened at all.

I found a function that pauses then clears the thumbnail. It doesn't reset DropZone though which prevents additional uploads. My efforts to combine the two have failed so I'm looking for some help on how to blend the two. I want a delay before removing the thumbnail and resetting DropZone.

```
success: function(file) {
 if (file.previewElement) {
  return file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success"),
    $(function(){
      setTimeout(function()
    { $('.dz-success').fadeOut('slow');},2500);
    });
    }
},
```

Comment: Wouldn't be easier just to show an alert or message and then clear up things as you have done before, with `this.removeFile(file);` inside the `setTimeout`?

Comment: I'd love to know how to put this.removeFile(file); inside the setTimeout. That's my quandry. And yes, I could use an alert but it just isn't the smooth, clean interface that I'd prefer in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so not sure how you init your Dropzone but I will do it the way I always do it for my projects:

**HTML**

```
<div id="DzUploadFile" class="dropzone"></div>
```

**JS**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
myDropzone = new Dropzone("#DzUploadFile", {
                url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("TempName", "ManagerFiles", new {
                 area = "",
                 Folder = Route, TmpFolderName = "File_"}))",
                paramName: 'files',
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/png,image/bmp",
                maxFilesize: 10,
                maxFiles: 1,
                success: function (file, response) {
                    file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
                    $(file.previewElement).find('[data-dz-name]').html(response.title);                        
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        myDropzone.removeFile(file);
                        console.log("File uploaded and removed from view");
                    }, 2500);
                }
            });
```

Of course you can always can set up your event listeners on the instance:

```
myDropzone.on("success", function (file, response) {
                file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
                $(file.previewElement).find('[data-dz-name]').html(response.title);
                setTimeout(function () {
                        myDropzone.removeFile(file);
                        console.log("File uploaded and removed from view");
                    }, 2500);
            });
```

Currently I can't give you a live example but currently work that way, on my projects.

NOTE:

- I use .NET MVC that's why the `url` is that way, just replace it with your own
- I'm just accepting images files, you can always just remove it or set your own [`acceptedFiles`](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-acceptedFiles)
- It should be a good idea to inform the user that you removed the file, using some nice looking and smooth alert/message like [SweetAlert](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-acceptedFiles), or the one you are implementing for the project.